# Is it possible to use Facetime with my Windows PC?

Tags: windows, facetime

Is it possible to use Facetime with my Windows PC?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is it possible to use facetime with my Windows PC?

No, it is not possible.

---

> FaceTime video calling requires an iPhone 4 or later, iPad 2 or later,
>   iPod touch (4th generation or later), or FaceTime-enabled Mac with a
>   Wi-Fi connection.

Source [Say hello to FaceTime for Mac](https://www.apple.com/mac/facetime/)